# Size/dimension/scope of a matrix? (Language-related)

Tags: matrices

I'm currently writing a math-related report. In this report I consider matrices $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ as well as dimensions of vector spaces. $M$ is neccesarily a square matrix, which is clear from the context I'm writing in.

The problem is that I would like to refer to both the $n$ as well as to the dimension of a related vector space in the same paragraph/section.

What I've done up to now is "the dimensions of the matrix $M$ is $n$", but the word "dimension" sounds very weird in this context. An alternative would be by using "size", but then the issue arises that the actual size is $n\times n$, and not $n$. Also, I think using the word "scope" will only confuse the reader, as I've seen no one using this word in this context.

How would you refer to this?

---

There is a similar question asked about this, [Dimension and size of an array, matrix, vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/dimension-and-size-of-an-array-matrix-vector) . However, the answer to this question only verifies my confusion, but does not give a good alternative.

Comment: Do you want to say something that would only be true if the matrices were $n \times n$, or is it OK to say something that would technically be true if the matrices were $m \times n$, ruling out that possibility using context (since you've said "$M$ is necessarily a square matrix")? In the latter case you could say something like "the number of columns" or "the dimension of the domain" or (exchanging the roles of $m$ and $n$) "the number of rows".

Comment: The report considers square matrices in the light of expressions computed from the determinant. Therefore the matrix must be a square-matrix. So the claims would only be true for $n\times n$-matrices.

Comment: I understand the situation, my question was about your style preferences. If it's OK to say something that would technically be true if the matrices were $m \times n$, but ruling out that possibility using the surrounding context, then you can say one of the things I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n \times n$ matrix is often referred to as a square matrix of order $n$.